# How to run a function after adding an element to ManyToManyField in django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, many-to-many, manytomanyfield

I'm writing an app which has users functionality, each user can follow another user to see his posts on a main view. My question is. Is there any clever way to trigger a notification when a new entry is added to `followed_users`?

The code of a field that stores users that are followed by a user:

```
    followed_users = models.ManyToManyField(
        "self",
        verbose_name=_("followed users"),
        blank=True,
        symmetrical=False,
        related_name="followers",
    )
```

and a corresponding method in view to follow a user:

```
    def follow(self, request: Request, **_kwargs):
        followed_user = self.get_object()

        if request.user.followed_users.filter(id=followed_user.id).exists():
            return Response({"detail": _("You already follow this user.")}, status=400)

        request.user.followed_users.add(followed_user)
        return Response()
```

I know I can invoke a function which creates a notification in follow() function but it's not very elegant for me.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/signals/#m2m-changed) for m2m signals. You can add your custom notification process with a `post_add` action